# Free Professional Standards Publications

Tags: ieee

Does anyone know of a place to get free publications of engineering standards like IEEE, ASME, SAE, and so forth.  The organizations themselves charge hefty fees for these publications and as far as I can tell the libraries that have copies have expensive membership dues as well.  The developers of Linux drivers for standard port adaptors must get the specifications from somewhere unless they reverse engineer sample hardware or something.

As an example, if a USB 4.0 standard ever gets published, where will literal coding specifications come from for development of port adaptor software or drivers?

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. Most likely the compnay Linux developers work for simply buy the specification (or they may even be involved in the development of the spec, so they get access anyway). Sometimes the draft specification is available (sometimes even through publicly accessible websites of the standard org), but if you want to implement a standard, you need to pay (or have a sponsor pay) for the spec.

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to the final ratified versions the drafts of standards documents are often made freely available online. There is often little substantial difference between drafts and final standards, but as Mark Rotteveel points in his comment, you need to pay if you want to claim that your implementation complies with the standard.

Drafts are often available for ISO standards. Also many IEEE standards have identical counterparts ratified by ISO.

Also many IEEE standards are available now at no charge via [IEEE Get program](http://standards.ieee.org/about/get/)

#### USB

You chose USB as an example. The Unified Serial Bus standard is maintained by the USB Implementers forum (USB). All specifications published by USB-IF a available on their [website](http://usb.org) under an 'AS-IS' license.

I repeat, this is not an IEEE, ASME, nor SAE standard and does not make a good example for the question.